# Scikit predict_proba output interpretation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am working with scikit-learn library in python. In the code below, I am predicting probability but I don't know how to read the output.

**Testing data**

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RF
from sklearn import cross_validation

X = np.array([[5,5,5,5],[10,10,10,10],[1,1,1,1],[6,6,6,6],[13,13,13,13],[2,2,2,2]])
y = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,2])
```

**Split the dataset**

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)
```

**Calculate the probability**

```
clf = RF()
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
pred_pro = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
print pred_pro
```

**The output**

```
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]]
```

The X_test list contains 3 arrays (I have 6 samples and test_size=0,5) so output has 3 too.

But I am predicting 3 values (0,1,2) so why I am getting only 2 elements in each array?

How should I read the output?

I also noticed, when I modify the number of distinct values in y, number of columns in output is always distinct count of y -1.

Comment: Welcome to CrossValidated.  Did you see my answer below?  If it solved your question, go ahead and mark it as the correct answer.  Otherwise, let me know what's missing and I'll try to clear it up for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at `y_train`.  It is `array([0, 0, 1])`.  This means your split didn't pick up the sample where y=2.  So, your model has no idea that the class y=2 exists.

You need more samples for this to return something meaningful.

Also check out [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) to understand how to interpret the output.

Comment: This is correct. If you set `y = np.array([0,2,1,0,1,2])` and `random_state=2` you'll now see 3 columns of output

Comment: The answer solved my question. Thank you very much. And in which order are the columns please? Its always ascending?

Comment: Run `clf.classes_`. Columns will be in that order.

Comment: Just like this: `clf.fit(X_train,y_train).classes_`?

Comment: I think that'll work but you can just run `clf.classes_` *after* you run `clf.fit(X_train,y_train)`

Comment: I have run it, no errors. But is there any way how to verify it?

Comment: What do you mean?  What exactly do you want to verify?

Comment: The order, lets say I want it ascending, can I verify that it is really ascending?